# Which event is triggered first on form save button

Tags: javascript

When you click "save" on a form , 2 jquery events I know get triggered. Actually I was using both but just today I realised one is enough :) . But still let's say you define both, which one would be triggered first. $("#btnSaveForm").click()  or $("#btnSaveForm").submit()

What I also noticed as soon as a click handler is triggered, the GUI basically freezes as long as this click handler is completely executed(Even if there is a ajax call done inside the handler). But still the GUI remembers what you did and executes the clicks afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

The order of which things are executed is as follows :

1. User clicks the submit button
2. The onclick function is executed
3. The browser submits the page to the url specified in the action of
   the form

Comment: A nice explanation if possible could you create a flow diagram?  adds that in the post.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-cdn-9fv60), the button triggers first and the form triggers right after.

Maybe you are using `sync` ajax handler if you are experiencing Frozen GUI after submitting your form.